# Problema con Muuri las imágenes se superponen unas sobre otras

Tags: javascript, html, css

a modo de practica estoy creando un portafolio para una persona ficticia y estoy usando la librería Muuri para la galería de imágenes. Mi problema es que las imágenes se superponen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://yaakov04.github.io/portafolio-graphic-designer/

Alguien sabe porque pasa esto? o como puedo arreglarlo?

El codigo completo esta en [github](https://github.com/yaakov04/portafolio-graphic-designer/tree/gh-pages)

Comment: Adjunta un [repro] a tu pregunta: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Buscando un poco más encontré que la solución era utilizar el método grid.refreshItems().layout(); cuando cargara la pagina, en codigo:

```
window.onload = function() {
  grid.refreshItems().layout();
};
```